# How to solve the Pidgin GTalk client not working on Windows 7 problem?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

When I try to connect my pidgin to my gtalk account it doesn't work anymore.
What should I do? The error is

> Not Authorized

I used

1. Protocol XMPP
2. Username without @gmail.com
3. Domain gmail.com (default)
4. Checked Require SSL/TLS (default)
5. Connect port 5222 (default)
6. File transfer proxies proxy.eu.jabber.org (default)

All other options are unchecked or empty

The instructions at [Google Talk Support](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24073) or [Google Talk Support Forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Talk/thread?tid=33479cc0f0c069e7&hl=en&fid=33479cc0f0c069e700049004abf496f8) didn't work for me

Comment: Some general troubleshooting questions: 1. What OS? Windows or Linux? 2. Is there anything we should know about your network or Internet acess? 3. Does Pidgin work with other IM protocols, or even Facebook's [XMPP Chat](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php)? 4. Does it work in any other client?

Comment: @digitxp Windows 7, gtalk works with official client, pidgin works as a msn messenger client.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you set the "Connect Server" option? It isn't in your list of settings but is mentioned on the [forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Talk/thread?tid=33479cc0f0c069e7&hl=en&fid=33479cc0f0c069e700049004abf496f8) you said didn't work.

Comment: @moberley I tried both ways. Today it began unexpectedly to work.

Comment: I think it began to work after I installed the facebook plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the connect server is talk.google.com

Check the password (Duh?)

Try unchecking the security, just to see it it will connect without it.

update pidgin?

Comment: I think it began to work after I installed the facebook plugin

Answer (score 32):

What solved this error for me was logging into http://accounts.google.com/  Then under the "Signing In" section I chose "Access for Less Secure Apps". It was disabled, and once I enabled that option, Pidgin was instantly able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for this, I missed that option in the account page, and most responses for "Not Authorized" are only for two-step verification problems.

Comment: My problem too. This was the first place that I found that even suggested looking at that setting. Many thanks!

Comment: This is the right solution. Work as well on Ubuntu 15.10. It could be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: This solves the issue, +1 for that; but I wonder will it make my gmail vulnerable? :o

Comment: @Ali_Waris No, from what I could find searching, and [google's own help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), google's "less secure apps" really only means "non-google apps" like *Mozilla Thunderbird,* and the security is at least as good.

Answer (score 8):

Look at [this post](http://mylinuxbook.com/how-to-get-pidgin-working-with-gtalk/)
**This worked for me:**

Go to your google accounts by logging in to http://accounts.google.com/
In the ‘Security’ menu (left side of the window), go to the 2-step verification section
Under this section.,

click the ‘Manage your application-specific passwords’ link.
Sign-in again (if prompted)

Set any name relevant to the application. For example, pidgin-messenger and hit the ‘Generate Password’ button.
Copy the password generated (along with the spaces, it doesn’t matter) and hit the ‘done’ button.

Now, hit the ‘Modify account’ button on the Pidgin window, paste the copied password in the ‘password’ text box and click the ‘save’ button. You will again be presented the ‘Add accounts’ window. In this window try again to tick the ‘Enabled’ check box

Comment: It's one correct answer here. Direct link: https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Comment: Indeed! This is the correct answer.

Comment: @DuckDodgers glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

I work for a security company, so things are locked down pretty tight inside the firewall.  Iwent to the advanced section for the XMPP client and selected use "old-style SSL" for connection security, 443 for connection port, and talk.google.com for connection server.  Now it's working fine.

Comment: That totally worked!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. I've discovered that my gtalk account was blocked by google (maybe) and that's why pidgin wasn't able to connect. So I downloaded [gtalk](http://www.google.com/talk/) and login for once. After logoff pidgin established connection to gtalk.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if your passwords contains the dollar sign($), it isn't parsed correctly on Pidgin and leads to "Not Authorized" errors

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a few hours struggling to get Pidgin work with 2-step verification. It looks like Google Accounts website structure has been changed, making all the instructions and links on the web outdated. It's especially misleading that Manage Apps and App Passwords are two different sections.

**Updated Guide for Adding App Specific Passwords to Google Account**

Here's how to navigate to App Passwords section:

```
Google Accounts > Signing in to Google > App Passwords
```

Or use the direct link below:

```
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
```

Answer (score 0):

i have multifactor authentication enabled. i had to create an app password for pidgin.

1. went to myaccount.google.com
2. clicked Sign in & Security
3. clicked "app passwords" (in Password & sign-in method box)
4. Select app -> Other. Give it a descriptive name.. like pidgin.
5. Enter this key in the password field in pidgin.

hope this helps some of you.